# Can you optimize a view with many UNION ALLs to external databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given these views in a Sql Server 2012 database:

```
create view vManyUnions as
    select 1 as p, a from vSubQuery_1
    union all
    select 2 as p, a from vSubQuery_2
    union all
    select 3 as p, a from vSubQuery_3
    ...
    union all
    select n as p, a from vSubQuery_n

create view vSubQuery_1 as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = something

create view vSubQuery_2 as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = somethingElse

create view vSubQuery_3 as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = somethingElseStill

...

create view vSubQuery_n as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = youGetTheIdea
```

And given this query:

```
select * from vManyUnions where p = 1
```

What optimizations, if any, can be made such that Sql Server 2012 only evaluates vSubQuery_1 when running the query?

*Note again, the sub query views call external databases.

Comment: Not sure why you need this many view instead of `select * from vManyUnions where p = 1` this why can't you use this `select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = something`

Comment: Sql Server 2012. @Fireblade, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @newbyca Both the queries will return the same result

Comment: Because in my case, the user of vManyUnions wouldn't know anything about the external database or the sub query views.

Comment: This question should probably be on the DBA stack because it's about a very specific request and optimizations done by SQL Server. For 'normal' union all statements SQL Server, in the similar queries I have done, will trivially eliminate fetching/building the result-sets that are filtered and can never be selected. Although this isn't to say how the views are accessed and/or if it varies (from my past observations) in particular case.

Comment: Show your actual execution plan. I expect that optimizer would eliminate unnecessary views from the `UNION`.

Comment: it seems like only INDEXES can help you  here

Comment: Thanks @user2864740, I posted it to the dba stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I moved this question to the dba forum:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96501/can-you-optimize-a-view-with-many-union-alls-to-external-databases

FOLLOW UP: This was an example I contrived from a much more complicated case (~1K subviews) where the execution planner includes more subqueries than the one subquery I expect. Thanks to those that replied and comfirmed that Sql should optimize queries against this type of view. It made me realize I was being lazy and hadn't actually tested my basic assumptions on how the optimizer works.

So I did that. I built a simple proof of concept and confirmed very fast that Sql optimizes the query. Following that, I worked more with the real-world view that still doesn't optimize. I found that, strangely, the planner is optimizing out many of the subviews. There are particular subviews that the planner always includes though. At this point I don't know why the planner always includes these particular subviews.